# Image not load in only production mode MERN Stack ChatApp

Tags: node.js, networking, loading, mern, cloudinary

When I run my Chatapp I made by MERN Stack technologies, it is running in local very well but after deploying in onrender, I cannot find why image it is not loading , some chatname list image is loading but navbar and chatbox image is not loading.
Note that I used cloudinary image to store the URL in my mongodb,
In the console code image url is successfully loaded , I shared below screenshot of that, but in the network tab not showing that image req is received.. Please resolve problem.

Successfully shows image url in console:

[image: IMAGE: successfully shows image url in console]

checkout my page output

Not show image in output:

[image: IMAGE : not show image in output]

Image is successfully load, why showing in console inspect code but not received in network tab of inspect.

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that's due to Mixed Content - the page containing the images is loaded over HTTPS, but the image URLs (based on the screenshot you shared) are attempted to be loaded over HTTP, therefore, they're blocked by the browser hence the broken image icon.

It's worth updating the code on your side which generates the image URLs to ensure they're using HTTPS.

If you are storing the URLs directly returned by Cloudinary then you could change your code to take the `secure_url` rather than the `url` property of the response which will contain the HTTPS URL.

If you have existing URLs stored in your database as-is then you could update those with a query to replace the protocol (`http` to `https`).

If you are using one of Cloudinary's SDKs to build the URLs to your images on the fly then you can include `secure: true` in the configuration object of the SDK (same level where you've configured the `cloud_name`, `api_key`, etc) and that will tell the SDK to generate URLs using HTTPS.